# Stacktrace inside of the eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an exception that's not getting handled very well. I'm at a line in the debugger where I have the exception in hand, but it's not in my code, so I can't just log it at that point. So I'm sitting in the debugger with the exception in my variables window and I'm trying to figure out how to get the stack trace from it so i can find where the exception originated and handle it better.

Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `Debug` Perspective, show the `Expressions` View.  Now you can add a expression of `e.printStackTrace()` where `e` is your variable.

Alternatively, you can change your expression to `getStackTrace()` and expand the `StackTraceElement` array in the `Expressions` output window.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you create an [Exception Breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-addexception_viewaction.htm?cp=1_4_7_0_1)? Then you don't have to manually debug through your code until the exception occurs, instead the debugger will just stop whenever that exception is thrown originally and you can see the *live* stacktrace in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the line where the problem is happening, you can set a breakpoint in the code and watch "Debug" tab, which will show you the stack:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the following trick. 
Go to the "expression" view and add expression `e.printStackTrace()`. The stack trace will be printed to your STDERR, i.e. to eclipse console if your application is running inside the Eclipse IDE.